# How to send data of dynamic field with ActiveForm submit yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I have `ActiveForm` field in Yii2 and I am creating some dynamic field in the form using jQuery. I want to know that how to send those newly created fields data with `ActiveForm` submit button?

My form is like below with newly generated fields

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id'=>'form-event']); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'title')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'location')->textInput(['class' => 'placepicker form-control']) ?>

</div>
<div class="container" id="eventTemplate">
     <input class="form-control" type="text" name="option[]" /> <!-- This fields are generated dynamically -->
     <input class="form-control" type="text" name="option[]" /> 
     <input class="form-control" type="text" name="option[]" />
</div>
```

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-danger' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

So I want to send the data of that field with the form submit. And I cannot declare that field in `model` as I don't know how many input field I will need.

Answer (score 0):

If `option` is your model field then you can use:

`<?= $form->field($model, 'option[]')->textInput() ?>`

Assuming that your `$model` variable class name is `Car` and on the `jQuery` click event you can do this:

```
var $input = '<input type="text" name="Car[option][]">';
$("#eventTemplate").append($input);
```

Comment: Thank you mate. I am looking for a nice article online for yii2 that how to create dynamic fields in active form according to user input but i havent got any nice article or example on it. If you come across anything like that than please let me know.

Comment: i tried that one but i was not able to modify it according to my needs. in that i could not figure out how to change the label name because it uses template and in my case i want different labels for different input fields.